# How to get digits from the date in php?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am storing the date in varchar format in database. I want to get the 8 digits number from the input date. Input date can be in any format like 28/08/2016 , 28-08-2016 or 28 Aug 2016 etc.

Now I tried to do this:

```
    $country = mb_substr($this->country, 0, 4);
    $username = $this->user_name;
    $converted_date = date('Y_m_d-H-i-s', strtotime($this->date_of_application));
    $this-> member_id = $country.$username.$converted_date;
```

I am concatenating strings and the date. So my input date is :
28/08/2016 and output I am getting is: 1970_01_01-04-00-00

I changed the timezone in php.ini file.

So I want the output as number 28082016. How Can I get this?

Comment: If input date format can be any format, and you don't know what format, then you have problems.... would `01/07/2016` be 1st July or 7th January? If you know the format, then use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` rather than `strtotime()` (which makes assumptions about format, such as treating `28/08/2016` as US format, and deciding that there is no month `28` in a year)

Comment: But storing dates as varchar in your database isn't sensible, store them as dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'Y_m_d-H-i-s'` is the format for the date. so if you want to concatenate the date to `28082016` this should do that:

```
$converted_date = date('dmY', strtotime($this->date_of_application));
```

Comment: I am not getting the time by the timezone which I have set as Indian/Mahe. I have set the default timezone in php.ini file as well in the  code like -  date_default_timezone_set('Indian/Mahe'); still I get output like this: 01011970 @WorkHardWork

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DateTime Class](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-examples)

```
$input = '28-08-2016';
$input = str_replace("/", "-", $input);
$date = new DateTime($input);
echo $date->format('dmY'); // 28082016

$input = '28 Aug 2016';
$input = str_replace("/", "-", $input);
$date = new DateTime($input);
echo $date->format('dmY');  // 28082016

$input = '28/08/2016';
$input = str_replace("/", "-", $input);
$date = new DateTime($input);
echo $date->format('dmY');  // 28082016
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date('dmY' , strtotime( your date in string));

Answer (score 0):

`28/08/2016` is incorrect notation for *Day, month and four digit year* Date format.
Each part should be separated with **dots, tabs or dashes** in such case:

```
$d = "28/08/2016";
$converted_date = date('Y_m_d-H-i-s', strtotime(str_replace("/", ".", $d)));

print_r($converted_date);  // "2016_08_28-00-00-00"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php